# Beginning Python functions and lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

*quick edit I am using python 3.4

I have just started to learn python in class, and although it seems like an easier language to deal with than C++ there are some things I haven't been able to work out.

I need to make a small function, that takes in some temperatures given in farenheit and converts them to celsius and puts them back in a list form. I have most of the code, I believe it should work. However, I keep getting an error that a variable has not been declared.

```
input_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]

def farenheit_to_celsius(data):         #function definition
    output_temps = []                   #create empty list
        for input in data:              #cycle through list
            ((input_temps-32)* 5/9)     #done to each item oninput_temps
    output_temps += [input]             #connects list to list
    return output_temps                 #returns output_temps with newvalues

 print(output_temps)                    #prints out output_temps to debug
```

The code is indented correctly on my editor. However, when I try to run it it says "output_temps" has not been declared. Also, I am trying to add a list to a list however I am not sure I am doing it correctly.

```
output_temps += [input]          #not 100% sure if this is right.
```

Comment: It certainly doesn't look properly indented here for example that print statement is off.

Comment: I was having issues with the logic, the indenting was off since this is my first time trying to figure out how to paste the code into the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `input` variable is not modified if you don't reassign them. Second, the modification in `output_temps` should be done inside the loop. Third and most important, the function should have been called (the scope of the `output_temps` ends after the execution of the function ends).

```
input_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]
def farenheit_to_celsius(data):         #function definition
    output_temps = []                   #create empty list
    for input in data:              #cycle through list
        input = ((input-32)* 5/9)     #done to each item oninput_temps
        output_temps += [input]             #connects list to list
    return output_temps                 #returns output_temps with newvalues

print(farenheit_to_celsius(input_temps))
```

`output_temps += [input]` is correct. It puts the `input` in a list with it being the only element and then adds it to `output_temps` . But, probably a better method would have been to use [append method on lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
output_temps.append(input)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did somehow deleted my " input = ((input-32)* 5/9) "  when I pasted. The reason I had the print statement as " print(output_temps) " is because that is how our instructor had it to be called.
# print result
print(output_temps)

Answer (score 0):

```
for input in data:              
    ((input_temps-32)* 5/9) # this should be input = (input - 32)*5/9
```

Int is immutable in Python.
You have some indents mistake in your code.
And you haven't call farenheit_to_celsius before you print output_temps.

```
input_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]

def farenheit_to_celsius(data):         #function definition
    output_temps = []                   #create empty list
    for input in data:              #cycle through list
        input =  ((input-32)* 5/9)     #done to each item oninput_temps
        output_temps += [input]             #connects list to list
        # I think use output_temps.append(input) will be better. But it's ok here.
    return output_temps                 #returns output_temps with newvalues

print(farenheit_to_celsius(input_temps))                    #prints out output_temps to debug
```

Comment: i thought int lists could be mutable. Only tuples were immutable. Thank you for the rest. A little rusty on passing function parameters

Comment: @Luis List is mutable， but Int not. So `((input_temps-32)* 5/9)` just generate a number but not change input_temps itself

Answer (score 0):

output_temps is being declared inside of your method, but is being referenced in your print statement which is not inside the method, which is why you're getting the error. Instead of printing output_temps, print your call to the method, which will return output_temps:

```
print(farenheit_to_celsius(my_data))
```

To add to a list in Python you can do this:

```
my_list.append(my_data)
```

Comment: Nooo! Don't declare it outside the function; you need to _call_ the function, which _returns_ `output_temps`.

Comment: Oops, you're right, that would be a lot nicer. @Cyphase

Answer (score 0):

```
input_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]


def farenheit_to_celsius(data):
    output_temps = []

    for input in data:
        ((input_temps-32)* 5/9)
        output_temps += [input]

    return output_temps
    print(output_temps)
```

You should be good right here, I just had to fix a few white-space errors in this program and output_temps += [input] okay it does not cause any errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're *defining* the function, but not *calling* the function. Just like in C++, none of the code in the function is run unless you call the function.

Also, even if you called the function before the `print`, the `print` wouldn't work because you're trying to access `output_temps`, which is a variable inside the function, from outside the function. The function returns `output_temps`, so you should do something like this:

```
output_temps = fahrenheit_to_celsius(input_temps)
```

You also have problems inside the function itself, which you haven't run into yet because you're not calling it in your code. First of all, `((input_temps-32)* 5/9)` is referring to the list of temperatures, not the current temperature you're iterating over. But even if you do `((input-32)* 5/9)`, that only computes the value you want, it doesn't save it. You need to do something with the result; for example, you could assign it to a variable:

```
result = (input_temps - 32) * (5 / 9)
```

Next, `output_temps += [result]` should be *inside* the `for` loop; otherwise you'd only add the last temperature to the output list after the `for` loop finishes. Also, you should use `output_temps.append()` to add a value to the list, not what you're doing now.

Here's a fixed version of your code, with some changes to variable names:

```
fahrenheit_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]

def fahrenheit_to_celsius(temps):
    celsius_temps = []
    for fahrenheit in data:
        celsius = (input_temps - 32) * (5 / 9)
        celsius_temps.append(celsius)
    return celsius_temps

 print(fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit_temps))
```

---

Now, generally, I would recommend having the function just work on one value, and handle the list outside the function.

This code ends up doing the same thing as the code above, but it's cleaner and more flexible.

```
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * (5 / 9)

fahrenheit_temps = [-20.0, -10.0, 5.0, 18.0, 50.0, 212.0]
celsius_temps = [fahrenheit_to_celsius(temp) for temp in fahrenheit_temps]

print(celsius_temps)
```

Comment: Yes I somehow managed to cut out "input = " from  input = "((input-32)* 5/9)" This is how he made the code just to get our feet wet, in python. Thanks for your input. Really like getting to see different ways of doing things.